# Why are images that are resized asynchronously initially too large when displayed in a ListView?

Tags: bitmap, android-asynctask, parse-platform, android-imageview, image-resizing

I am downloading Parse data fields from parse.com and resizing an image contained in each asynchronously. When the view inflates, the first page of images are not resized. When the view is recycled, they are displayed correctly.

I first tried to resize the images in the `done` part of the `GetDataCallback` and saw the big pictures. Next, I implemented the threading myself with the same results: first screen of images initially displayed incorrectly but then fixed when they leave the screen and come back.

As a test, I next tried getting the data directly (not `getDataInBackground`) and resizing and that worked fine, but obviously the processing time was increased. I believe that the issue has something to do with threading due to this test.

Some code:

```
            @Override
            public void done(List<Listing> listingList, ParseException e) {
                /* scale and save the image back to parse object */
                final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d("listing", "Retrieved " + listingList.size() + " listings");
                    /* clear adapter before populating */
                    adapter.clear();
                    /* iterate through listings and create listing objects */
                    for (Listing listingObject : listingList) {
                        //listingObject.resizeImage(scale);
                        new ResizeImages().execute(listingObject);
                        listings.add(listingObject);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Log.d("listing", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
```

Asynchronous resizing:

```
private class ResizeImages extends AsyncTask<Listing, Void, Listing> {
    protected Listing doInBackground(Listing... params) {
        Listing listing = params[0];

        final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        try {
            byte[] data = listing.getFile().getData();
        /* Decode the byte array into BitMap to be displayed on device */
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory
                    .decodeByteArray(
                            data, 0,
                            data.length);

                /* scale image and put back into parse object */
            if (scale <= 1.0) {
                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 134, 134, false);
            } else if (scale <= 1.5) {
                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 200, 200, false);
            } 

            ...

            /* put image back into byte data and put back in "this" */
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            byte[] scaledData = stream.toByteArray();
            bitmap.recycle();

            Log.d("Resizer", "Image resized.");
            ParseFile photoFile = new ParseFile("image.jpeg", scaledData);
            listing.setFile(photoFile);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return listing;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Listing listing) {
        Log.d("Resizer: ", "Resizing done");

    }
}
```

**EDIT**

My fix involved changing `onPostExecute' to:

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Listing listing) {
            Log.d("Resizer: ", "Resizing done");
            listings.add(listing);          // this line from UI thread moved here
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // this line was new
        }
```

I provide a more generalized way to resize bitmaps asynchronously in an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the problem was that the adapter was not notified that the data had changed. So when the ListView pulled the first few pictures, they were the original sized ones. To make this more generic and hopefully help someone in the future, here is how to resize bitmaps asynchronously:

```
// in your UI thread
new ResizeImages().execute(mBitmap);

// in your class
private class ResizeImages extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, Listing> {
    protected Listing doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {
        Bitmap bitmap = params[0]; // grab the first bitmap.. could grab more and 
                                   // do multiple per thread
        try {  
            /* scale image however you wish. here we scale to 200x200 px */
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 200, 200, false);

            /* put image back into byte data if you need to */
            //ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            //bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
            //byte[] scaledData = stream.toByteArray();

            /* put data back into bitmap if you need to */
            //Bitmap scaledBitmap = BitmapFactory
            //  .decodeByteArray(
            //           scaledData, 0,
            //           scaledData.length);

            /* recycle unneeded bitmap */
            bitmap.recycle();

            Log.d("Resizer", "Image resized.");

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
                Log.d("Resizer: ", "Resizing done");
                resizedBitmap = bitmap; // save resized bitmap into your class
                                        // variable
                bitmaps.add(bitmap); // here bitmaps is an list of bitmaps,     
                                      // like List<Listing> listingList
                /* notify adapter that the data has changed */
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```